# "No network adapters were detected" error EXSI 5.1 installation in Acer APE961

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am receiving the  "No network adapters were detected" error when installing the VMware ESXI 5.1 in Linux Acer server (Model APE961).

```
Processor :- AMD Athlon(tm) Processor LE-1640
Model APE961
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem?

BR//

Krishna

Comment: Acer doesn't list any computer model APE961. Acer only lists one desktop computer that comes with the LE-1640 processor. Almost all of Acer's products come with Realtek NICs, which are pieces of crap, and unlikely to work well if you can find the right driver.

Answer (score 2):

That system doesn't appear on the [VMware HCL](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php) for ESXi 5.1. You should select compatible hardware.

Sometimes vendors distribute custom ESXi images for hardware not on the HCL. If you purchased this from Acer and they listed it as compatible with ESXi 5.1, then contact them for details about how to get their custom ESXi image.